# How to restore or rebuy deleted iTunes audiobook purchase?

Tags: iphone, itunes, audiobook

I lost my copy of a downloaded audio book from iTunes. I also accidentally deleted my computer copy.

I am willing to rebuy the audiobook but iTunes will not let me rebuy the audiobook. It just tells me I have already bought it.

Is there any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can speak to Apple support. Tell them what happened and they will sometimes allow you to redownload your audiobooks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's one of the things that you can't re-download from the iTunes Store (others are Tones and iPod games).

Comment: This is why I hate apple sometimes.